# Insert range of values into a multidimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a multidimensional array where the first column contains identifiers and the adjacent columns contains data relevant to that identifier. So for instance I would like to create an array with the following structure:

```
Banana  10  20  30  40
Coconut 5   10  2   4
Apple   3   4   5   6
```

The construction of the array begins with the definition of the relevant identifiers. So for instance in the above that would be Banana, Coconut and Apple. The data I use to construct the array would have a layout as in the below:

```
Banana  10  20  30  40
Parrot  5   3   1   4
Apple   3   4   5   6
Car     10  20  30  40
Donkey  4   12  3   0
Coconut 5   10  2   4
```

As such, I start out by defining the Banana, Coconut and Apple identifiers and then want to automatically populate my array based on a loop through of identifier name in the data (I have defined this as "INPUT"). However, I am unsure of how to correctly insert the adjacent data in my array every time there is a match of identifiers. I would much appreciate if someone can explain how I can do this based on the code below.

```
identifierArray = Array("Banana", "Coconut", "Apple")
NumElements = UBound(identifierArray) - LBound(identifierArray) + 1

For Each Element In identifierArray
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To NumElements, x)
    arr(i, 0) = identifierArray(i)
    i = i + 1
Next Element

For Each cell In ws.Range("INPUT")
    For Each Element In identifierArray
        If cell.Value = Element Then

         [Need help here]

        End If
    Next Element
Next cell
```

I don't need help with creating VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH solutions as that is not relevant to the above.

Comment: Don't you have this data on your worksheet? Because you can just `arr = Range("A1:E7").Value` and you get a 2D array like your sheet.

Comment: Note that in an array `arr(1 To 10, 1 To 5)` you can only `ReDim` the second parameter `1 To 5` but not the first one `1 To 10` without loosing the data. Therefore you cannot add "rows" but only "columns" to that array.

Comment: If you are looking to use an identifier, you may want to look at using a collection or dictionary instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill an array from a range on your sheet like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim arr

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        arr = .Range("A1:E6")
    End With

End Sub
```

So a range like this:

[image: Data]

Turns into a array like this:

[image: Array]

So you don't need to loop at all, which means faster  execution and cheaper to code.